# Font Inspector data from the DOM

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

Is it possible to get the Firefox developer tools Font Inspector data programmatically from the DOM? I.e., getting the used font from the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the final CSS style for certain elements? You can use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle):

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('post-form')).fontFamily
```